# tortoisesvn + network drives

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, network-drive

I have a subversion repo on a network drive, Only I use the network drive, but from multiple computers.  On computer A, where I started it from, tortoisesvn works fine, but from other computers, I only get the option to "Upgrade working copy" which doesn't do anything then I click it.  I am wondering why this is? and what I have to do to make it work for me on both computers?

I searched the tortoise svn site and saw that they don't suggest using network drive, but only because multiple people could write at the same time.

Comment: If I understand your question.  You have checked the specific repository out on a network drive? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That is Correct.

Comment: Sadly.  You are running into the fact that normally tortoise-svn places hidden files on the computer when a repository is checked out.  So the intial pc has those files since its the pc that checked it out.  If you could find those files then you could transfer those files to each pc.  Might be easier to not use a network drive, and checkout the repostory on each pc.

Comment: You should post this as an Answer.

Comment: Post what exactly?  I am just describing my personal knowlege of how one specific solution works when a repository is checked out.

Comment: I don't think TortoiseSVN stores anything special about the repository or working copy, outside the working copy itself, that would interfere in this way. You can copy-paste entire working copies and have wholly independent fully-functional working copies, this wouldn't work if TortoiseSVN had hidden stuff on your PC needed to work with the working copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure that you are all using the same version of tortoisesvn?
I'm doing something similar with different vms running on the same physical host and i've only had a problem if the working copy was checked out using an old version of svn.

That could explain why the others only see an upgrade option

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/de/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html

Comment: I did.  I got 1.8.11 on both of them.